# Is there significance in a function having an infinite number of derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For example, we can define a function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 & \text{if } x < 2 \\ 4 \cdot(x - 1) & \text{if } x \ge 2 \end{cases}$$

This function seems to have a derivative.

$$f'(x) = \begin{cases} 2x & \text{if } x < 2 \\ 4 & \text{if } x \ge 2 \end{cases}$$

However, $f$ has no second derivative at $2$. Contrast this to $\sin$, which has an infinite number of derivatives. It seems that $\sin$ is somehow "smoother" than $f$.

Is there any significance to this?

Comment: My understanding is that you're asking for some kind of intuition behind the difference between a $k$-differentiable map and an $m$-differentiable map. Could you make it more clear if this is not the case?

Comment: What do you mean by $k$-differentiable maps?

Comment: Diff $k$ times but not $k+1$.

Comment: Yes, I was asking whether or not $k$-differentiability is important anywhere, and if $\infty$-differentiable maps are somehow a special class of functions.
In fact, "$k$-differentiability" may actually be an answer, since having a name for it means it is at least somewhat significant

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness

Comment: Smooth functions are nice because they form the the largest class of functions on which differentiation is an operation into the same class. If you take a $k$ times differentiable function, its derivative needn't be $k$ times differentiable. But a derivative of an infinitely differentiable function is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: That answers the question. I can't accept comments though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wojowu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/127263/wojowu), [Hans Lundmark](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1242/hans-lundmark) and [Arnaud Mortier](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/480423/arnaud-mortier) answered the question in the comments: This is called smoothness, and $\sin$ is an infinitely smooth function.